# Symfony2 findBy method with property from relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, findby

I'm wondering if it's possible to querying doctrine entities by a property from a relation.

Here is an example :

```
Entity A fields :


-> title
-> content
-> description
-> date


Entity B fields :

-> title
-> link ( entity b )
-> date
```

Is it possible to querying Entity B by link->title property such as the following :

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository("acmeAppBundle:EntityB")->findBy(array( "title" => "test", "link.title" => "example" ) );
```

Currently I'm achieving this with a custom function from Entity B repository, but may be I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use findBy like this. FindBy is only there to fetch very basic things. Generally it's considered as a best practice to use repository calls, because for example, if you here fetch all objects where title is test and then you get from A all B entity, then entity B will be fetched separately, while in a repository call you can use join, so only one query will be sent to your DB.